# jQuery droppable and sortable with PHP ids

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to implement [jQuery UI droppable and sortable example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/shopping-cart.html) into one of my PHP scripts...

The idea is after user drags and sort out everything to export playlist ids in sorted order and process them in PHP... I have found [this example](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dynamic-dragn-drop-with-jquery-and-php/) but I'm stuck in the point where I should pass playlist_id to jQuery. So far I've been playing with some stuff, but each time my recordsArray[] contains 'undefined' values or I mess up complete output :)

Please help me with this easy one :)

My jQuery part looks like this:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {
        $( "#playlist li" ).draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $( "#export ol" ).droppable({
            activeClass: "ui-state-default",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
            accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $( this ).find( ".placeholder" ).remove();
                // GET ID SOMEHOW HERE!
                $( "<li id='???'></li>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
            }
        }).sortable({
            items: "li:not(.placeholder)",
            sort: function() {
                $( this ).removeClass( "ui-state-default" );
            },
            update: function() {
                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize");
                $.post("<?php echo site_url('export/all/'); ?>", order);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and PHP part:

```
echo "<div id=\"playlists\">";
    echo "<h3>PLAYLISTS</h3>";
    echo "<div id=\"playlist\">";
        echo "<div>";
            echo "<ul>";
                foreach ($all_playlists as $playlist) {
                    echo "<li id=\"recordsArray_&lt;".$playlist['playlist_id']."&gt;\">";
                    echo "<font size=\"1\">".getFormattedDateAndTime($playlist['time'])."</font> ".br();
                    echo "<font size=\"2\"><b>".$playlist['playlist_name']."</b></font>";
                    echo "</li>";
                }
            echo "</ul>";
        echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "<div id=\"export\">"; 
    echo "<h3>EXPORT</h3>";
    echo "<div class=\"ui-widget-content\">"; 
        echo "<ol>";
            echo "<li class=\"placeholder\">DRAG HERE...</li>"; 
        echo "</ol>";
    echo "</div>"; 
echo "</div>";
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ui object in drop event is an actual element being dropped, so to get the id

```
ui.draggable.attr('id')
```

Comment: @errata haha; nema frke buraz ::)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do two things:

- instead of `$( "#playlist li" ).draggable({` must be `$( "#playlist ul" ).draggable({`
- start the javascript code via $(document).ready(function(){})